# Checking if both attribute and value exist using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm reading in a web page using beautifulSoup in python.
Many elements are spans, but with different values for their class attribute. e.g.

```
Value1 = property.findChild("span", {"class" : "search-result-Val1"}).text
Value2 = property.findChild("span", {"class" : "search-result-Val2"}).text
```

The issue is if a user didn't enter a value for Val1 or Val2 when saving their item, they won't appear on the search results page, so I need to check if a span tag exists, wtih an attribute "class" with a specific value for that attribute, before I can try to extract its value.

How might I do this? GetAttr() method doesn't help as it just tells me if the attribute exists, but I can't check the value of that attribute, which is the differentiating factor in this case.

Comment: can you provide the link of the page you are trying to scrape ?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific instance you are looking for the class attribute.

In this case you can do a `property.findChild("span")["class"]` and then check to see if it contains one of the classes you want.

Answer (score 0):

use [list](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) filter:

> If you pass in a list, Beautiful Soup will allow a string match against **any** item in that list.

```
property.findChild("span", class_=["search-result-Val1","search-result-Val2"] )
```